# Dynamic textfield creation in coldfusion

Tags: forms, dynamic, coldfusion

I'm fairly new to Coldfusion, we are using MX 7, and i'm trying to figure out how to populate a page based on user input. The goal is to have the user specify how many products they want to input into an order form and display that many textfields.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I found how to do this using jQuery but i'm still having a problem populating the textfields with information from the database. Here is what I have:

```
function fillfields(oSel){
  var oForm=oSel.form;
  switch(oSel.options[oSel.selectedIndex].value){
    case '0': break;
    case'1':oForm.ShipCompany2.value="#company_name.Company#";
            oForm.ShipName2.value="#company_name.Name#";
            oForm.ShipLine3.value="#company_name.Address1#";
            oFrom.ShipLine4.value="#company_name.Address2#";                  
            oForm.ShipCity2.value="#company_name.City#";
            oForm.ShipState2.value="#company_name.State#";
            oForm.ShipZipcode2.value="#company_name.ZipCode#";
            break;
    case '2':
      break;
    case '3':
      break;
   }
}
```

This won't work. Is there another way to populate this?

Comment: Are you looking to do this on the client side or the server side?

Comment: client side would be prefered

Comment: This isn't directly a ColdFusion question then.  You probably want to search for something like "adding new lines to a form with javascript" on Google.  jQuery would probably be easier.  Then you just need to have a form field naming convention that ColdFusion could handle.

Comment: Yes I just did a search for jQuery and got the answer I was looking for. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: What are you getting when you run this code?

Comment: it populates the field with the exact string. For example ShipCompany2 displays #company_name.Company# instead of the actual name

Comment: in ColdFusion, all these fields need to be in a CFOUTPUT tag.

Comment: This is in a javascript though. How can I work with it?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your CFM page, you have code that looks like:

```
function fillfields(oSel){
  var oForm=oSel.form;
  switch(oSel.options[oSel.selectedIndex].value){
    case '0': break;
    case'1':oForm.ShipCompany2.value="#company_name.Company#";
            oForm.ShipName2.value="#company_name.Name#";
            oForm.ShipLine3.value="#company_name.Address1#";
            oFrom.ShipLine4.value="#company_name.Address2#";                  
            oForm.ShipCity2.value="#company_name.City#";
            oForm.ShipState2.value="#company_name.State#";
            oForm.ShipZipcode2.value="#company_name.ZipCode#";
            break;
    case '2':
      break;
    case '3':
      break;
   }
}
```

Modify this to:

```
<cfoutput>
    function fillfields(oSel){
      var oForm=oSel.form;
      switch(oSel.options[oSel.selectedIndex].value){
        case '0': break;
        case'1':oForm.ShipCompany2.value="#company_name.Company#";
                oForm.ShipName2.value="#company_name.Name#";
                oForm.ShipLine3.value="#company_name.Address1#";
                oFrom.ShipLine4.value="#company_name.Address2#";                  
                oForm.ShipCity2.value="#company_name.City#";
                oForm.ShipState2.value="#company_name.State#";
                oForm.ShipZipcode2.value="#company_name.ZipCode#";
                break;
        case '2':
          break;
        case '3':
          break;
       }
    }  
</cfoutput>
```

This will pick up the fields from the company_name structure, assuming that the company_name struture exists when you are rendering this section of code.